# Changing the expand and collaps icons in the PrimeNG tree

Tags: tree, icons, primeng, primeng-treetable

I'm using the tree component from PrimeNG. Does anyone knows how I can change the expand and collapse icons ? My target is to get a plus and minus instead of the `fa-caret-down` and `fa-caret-right`.

So from

[image]

to

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following CSS to your component:

```
::ng-deep .fa-caret-right::before {
  content: "\F067";
}

::ng-deep .fa-caret-down::before {
  content: "\F068";
}
```

[**Plunker example**](http://plnkr.co/edit/dTrsmv?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks! that was what I was searching for.